# Transcend External Hard disk not giving full storage

Tags: external-hard-drive

I purchase a Transcend external hard disk with 640 GB, but it only able to store 32 GB. The unit working perfectly. I reformat it still the same, why.

Answer (score 0):

1. Connect it to a windows PC.
2. Open Run or press 'Windows key + X'.
3. Enter diskmgmt.msc, press ok.
4. Disk management opens up, find your 640 gb hdd listed among all the drives.
5. At the bottom you will find blocks of partitions on your drive. Find a partition labelled RAW (it will be represented with a black line at bottom of the block)

***proceed only if you see RAW partition

6.Right click on it , click 'New Simple Volume'.

7. Volume creation wizard opens up, if you are not sure how to create a new volume clicking next throughout will get the work done ( but check changes being made)
8. Check the size of your drive it should be somewhere around 600 gb.